# Performance check between shared cluster and laptop with Intel(R)Core™ i7

Tags: linux, windows, performance, cluster-computing, cplex

I am not really familiar with shared clusters, but I am assuming performance should not differ much in terms of completing a single task when compared with a laptop processor. I have a C++ code which I ran on my laptop with Intel(R)Core™ i7-4558U 2.80 GHz CPU and 16.0 GB RAM, with the operating system of 64 bit Windows 10. On the other hand, I have results of the same code from a publication which belong to the tests conducted on a shared cluster with Intel Xeon 2.3 GHz CPU and 4 GB memory limit with Linux operating system. The program uses CPLEX as the solver: my laptop has IBM Cplex 12.7 whereas previous runs used IBM CPLEX 12.4 (Cplex, 2012). My results seem to take **300 times more** than the reported results of the previous run. ***Does this much difference make sense? If so what could be the driver behind it?***

Comment: From your description you are comparing absolutely different things.It's like asking why does a yacht running X times faster than a car? What could be the driver behind it? The short answer is - a lot of things.

Comment: Do you say, It might make sense to get this much difference in the run times even though my CPLEX version is newer and the processor on my laptop is better?

Comment: Different hardware, different operating system, different software versions, different people running the experiment, unclear methods of measuring. You just cannot compare the results. Any difference will make sense in this case. Also I'd take any numbers from publications with a pinch of salt.

Comment: If I did not get wrong, you are basically saying "results are not comparable", which makes sense to me. This means I have to make sure I am running on the same computer/cluster, same operating system, same software in order to make a comparison.

Comment: That's right, also in publications they don't always tell you the true story  ;)

Comment: :) go it; thanks..

Comment: One more (obvious) observation - the original test was run on a cluster. This probably means the task is parallelizable.

Comment: That is right , CPLEX has parallel running capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be attributed to *performance variability* (see, for example, section 5 of the MIPLIB 2010 paper [here](http://mpc.zib.de/index.php/MPC/article/view/56)). In a nutshell, minor differences in problem formulation (e.g., order of constraints, input format, etc.), or running on different platforms, can have a great effect on the time to solve. With CPLEX 12.7, you can use the interactive to help you [evaluate variability](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/InteractiveOptimizer/topics/evaluateVariability.html).

Comment: Thanks for the variability evaluation Ryan. The owner of the publications shared their code and the inputs, relying on this fact, there is no difference on the input side. But to completely digest your answer: I am not able to download the MIPLIB 2010 link.

Comment: I've updated the link (maybe that will work for you). This is  Koch et al., "MIPLIB 2010 - Mixed Integer Programming Library version 5", Mathematical Programming Computation, 2011.